# Killing a Sub Process while using Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, google-url-shortener

I need to shorten multiple urls using the Google Shortener API. Since each shortening process is not interdependent I decided to use multiprocessing library in Python.

raw_data is a data frame which contains my long url. Api_Key is a list which contains api key from multiple google accounts(as i dont want to hit the limit of api usage for a day)

Here is the underlying code.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from multiprocessing import  Pool
import math
import requests

raw_data["Shortened"] = "xx"

Api_Key_List1 = ['Key1',
           'Key2',
           'Key3']

raw_data = raw_data[0:3]

LongUrl = raw_data['SMS Click traker'].tolist()
args = [[LongUrl[index], Api_Key_List1[index]] for index,value in enumerate(LongUrl)] 
print("xxxx")

def goo_shorten_url(url,key):
    post_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=%s'%key
    payload = {'longUrl': url}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    time.sleep(2)
    r = requests.post(post_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    return(json.loads(r.text)["id"])

def helper(args):
    return goo_shorten_url(*args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(processes = 3)
    data = p.map(helper,args)
    print("main")
    raw_data["Shortened"]=data
    p.close()
    print(raw_data)
```

Using this code i am successfully shorten multiple urls in one go thus saving a lot of time. Here are some questions which i am having difficulty in finding answers to:

1. What is the optimal number of sub-processes that I shall be running? (I am using a simple quadcore processor 8 gb ram laptop, Windows 7)
2. Sometimes due to some issues the api does not return a shortened url. The code is stuck forever. This was my experience when i was not using multiprocess. What happens to the process in such case?
3. Assuming the subprocess will get stuck for a long set of urls (70 000). How do I kill it and also ensure the code safely returns me all remaining shortened urls with proper matching in the data frame?
4. How can I identify those urls which were not Shortened?

I am a newbie to python programming, bear with me. This will help me better understand the inner working of multiprocessing.

Comment: The optimal number will very much depend on where the google shortener's time is spent. If it works locally, then it will be the number of processors, perhaps plus a couple. If it is measurably disk or network traffic bound the width of that pipe will be the limiting factor. It seems more likely that the main work is performed by some google cloud server, in which case you could keep pushing up until you either do reach the network pipe limit, or google enforces some limit based on IP address.

Comment: @GemTaylor the limit for a single api key is currently 1 lakh per day. Normally it takes about 1 to 1.5 sec to return the shortened url (depending on the network).

Comment: lakh = a hundred thousand per day ~ 1.15 per second, and interesting that they take 1-1.5 seconds each. But that probably isn't related to the number of "simultaneous" requests that they will accept. I'm sure there is a limit to that as well. As with processors it is worth going slightly over that limit so that the server is kept fed, assuming it doesn't just reject the overflow. If there is no such limit, I guess you might be looking at low hundreds.

Comment: You might hit RAM/VM limits! You might consider using some sort of message pump rather than parallel threads. A proper event driven pump on a single thread is likely to be just as effective, and more efficient, and makes it easy to do timeout detection, assuming you have an API that allows you to split send and receive..

Comment: FYI: This is not a good use case for multiprocessing. It's a perfect textbook case for `gevent` or `aiohttp`; I suggest you look at one of those instead.